# Is "ich biere gern" a correct sentence to use instead of "ich trinke Bier gern"?

Tags: grammaticality

I  was scanning through a seminar about "Grammatik und Design" which was held in Germany last month and found "ich biere gern" in it. Is it a correct term to use?

> Außerdem entstand auch in einigen Fällen
>   der Neologismus „Ich biere gern“. Der Einfluss von Design führt somit sogar zur
>   Weiterentwicklung der Sprache und ist damit nicht zu unterschätzen.

If yes, does it apply to all kinds of drink or just "bier"?

Comment: Currently it's incorrect but it seems the text/seminar is about creating (designing) new elements in a language. The phrase is even declared as a neologism.

Comment: @musiKk: Yeah, I think that's the case and you're right but it's written there anyway, one would think it's a normal sentence and can be used like everything else.

Comment: Well, it's true that the term being declared as a neologism may suggest it's already widely used. It might even be the case. I have to concur with nd01 in that I never heard of it though. However most natives—albeit being puzzled—may guess what it means and I can imagine this being some sort of trend word in certain societies.

Comment: My guess is this phrase was coined as a persiflage of the once ubiquitous advertising slogan "Ich rauche gern". Both form and content are very similar.

Comment: Thank you for this post! As a native speaker I really like this expression and its already widley used within my cricle of friends! :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Are you sure that you didn't misread the sentence - or that it was a typo? As a native speaker, I have never heard of *bieren*. I would consider it incorrect.

As for other drinks, it is also not possible. There are, however, some constructs that at least sound like a drink would be in them, even if they mean something different:

- *ich weine* = *I am weeping*
- *ich wässere* = *I am watering* (e.g. plants)

### Update after reading the PDF:

I suppose, this is [the PDF for "Grammatik und Design"](http://www.linse.uni-due.de/tl_files/PDFs/Projekte/Dringenberg_G&D6-11.pdf). The sentence used is in page 3:

> Außerdem entstand auch in einigen Fällen der Neologismus „Ich biere
>   gern“.

The text explicitly states that the sentence in the question is a neologism, i.e. it is a language construct that has been newly formed. Many neologisms are not considered correct for quite a while, yet they can be used to command the attention of the listener/reader. Maybe, after a while, this construct then will be considered correct. An example for this would be another advertisment-related neologism "Hier werden Sie geholfen", which is also not considered correct, but is used in noncommercial context and originated from an ironic manner.

Comment: No, I didn't misread .. I have it open right at the moment in pdf version. I added the sentence in my question. I guess you're right anyway, thank you for your answer.

Comment: +1 now after the edit.

Comment: This reminds me of "science is a verb now!", see also http://books.google.com/books?id=xb6ie6PqYhwC&lpg=PA113&ots=23_jdh4sqe&dq=english%20verb%20contact%20style&pg=PA113#v=onepage&q&f=false

Answer (score 7):

#### No, "bieren" is not a German word!

However for marketing purposes new words or new compositions of exisiting words may be invented to put a message forward be it either by attracting people because of the obvious error or be it from space limits on a product's label, or on an advertisment.

Interestingly the example you gave is still well understood as it follows general rules of conjugation similar to known verbs like:

> **frieren:** ich friere, Du frierst, wir frieren...

*"Bieren"* is not an exisiting verb in German but still we can conjugate it like this

> **bieren:** ich biere, Du bierst, wir bieren...

as we could also conjugate any other fantasy word:

> **gigilieren:** ich gigliere, Du gigilierst, wir gigilieren...

If the slogan created was good enough this newly invented word may eventually enter common colloquial usage. That of course is like winning a lottery for the company that created the slogan but it happens.

Comment: +1 for *gigilieren*.

Answer (score 3):

Interestingly, it is not uncommon in English to use the word "beer" as a verb, although I've only ever heard it in the context of someone saying:

> "Beer me!" (Meaning "give me a beer")

Comment: There are many other similiar words in English, such as "I glove my hands" etc. They make the sentence short and give it grip. I think this should be one of the things where I don't dislike neologies...

Answer (score 0):

If I came across the term "ich *biere* gern" without specific context, I'd assume *biere* to be the conjunctiv of (an inexistent verb) *bären*.

Of course, then, since *bären* as a verb does not exist, I'd further assume it could be an abbreviation of *gebären*, so that I'd internally translate:

> ich biere gern, wenn ich noch jünger wäre

to

> I'd like to give birth if I was younger.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a curiosity: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bieren claims that there is a German verb "bieren", qualifies it as "informal", and even conjugates it (automatically) for all sorts of tenses and moods. Caveat lector.

Answer (score 0):

As Takkat already pointed out, this is not (yet!) correct german. I would consider it an anglicism, scince it is a feature of the English language that you can make a verb out of (almost?) every noun. German rather has the opposite feature: in German you can make a noun out of every verb.