# Was bedeutet "buzzern"?

Tags: meaning, verb

http://www.the-voice-of-germany.de/news/voting-bestes-team-1.2995534

> Alle Teams sind voll besetzt. Da stellt sich die Frage aller Fragen: Wer hat sich eurer Meinung nach das beste Team zusammengebuzzert?

I entered "buzzern" and "zusammenbuzzern" into dict.leo.org and came up empty.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't find it because it's a [neologism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neologism). I think it comes from their use of "buzzer" devices, large pushbutton switches that give off a buzz when pressed (actually, technically, the buzzer is the small thing - often a piezo speaker - that creates the buzzing sound, but the meaning has transferred over to those big red [switches](http://www.heise.de/foto/galerie/the-buzzer-0046fd027098716acedff96667d9a6b1/)).

So, "buzzern" means hitting the buzzer button. As to what such a "buzz" means in the context of their show, I don't know. It's probably some form of voting, so "zusammenbuzzern" would mean compiling the list of candidates via buzzer-voting.

Answer (score 8):

"Buzzern" is not a real german word. But just like in [this example](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/3160/is-ich-biere-gern-a-correct-sentence-to-use-instead-of-ich-trinke-bier-gern) one can easily make up a word, which most german speakers will understand because it happens within a set of rules. In the case of "Buzzern", it means to use a "Buzzer". Germans think of a buzzer only as the big red button used in gameshows, which activates an acoustic signal when pressed. "Zusammenbuzzern" is similar, but has a connotation of "build something using a buzzer", just like "zusammenschrauben", "zusammenkleben" or "zusammenstellen".

Answer (score 3):

The verb "*buzzern"* (derived from the English loanword ["*Buzzer"*](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Buzzer)) was used in Germany starting from about 1999. Its almost exclusive meaning is the act of pressing a buzzer in a TV gameshow.

#### Examples of early usage:

> *Die Finalrunde beginnt mit dem sogenannten Buzzern: Die Frage darf nur von demjenigen beantwortet werden, der zuerst auf seinen Knopf drückt. Sobald einer der Kandidaten auf diese Weise dreimal richtig geantwortet hat, darf er bestimmen, wer die nächste Frage bekommt.*<sup>[Jungle World 8/1999](http://jungle-world.com/artikel/1999/07/31812.html)</sup>
>
> *"Der große Preis" feierte seine größten Erfolge zu Zeiten, als das **"Buzzern"** noch nicht erfunden war. "Buzzern" kommt vom englischen Verb "to buzz" - summen. Und statt wie einst Wim Thoelke die Gäste anzuweisen, die roten Knöpfe zu drücken, heißt es heute: "Buzzern Sie mal!"* <sup>[Berliner Zeitung, 2.2.2002](http://www.berliner-zeitung.de/archiv/buzzern-sie-mal-,10810590,9970862.html)</sup>
>
> *Schnell **buzzern** und richtig raten - Im Finale schließlich spielen
> die Teams gleichzeitig - hier geht es nicht nur darum, wer den
> Begriff errät, sondern auch, wer schneller auf den Buzzer drückt.* <sup>[Kabel 1 Pressemeldung 04.06.2002](http://www.presseportal.de/pm/7841/353559/-dingsda-die-gameshow-mit-dem-uups-ist-wieder-da-ab-6-juni-2002-praesentiert-thomas-ohrner-12-neue)</sup>